# autofill a cpp file based on the .h file

Tags: c++

suppose I have x.h

```
class X {
void f();
void g();
}
```

in x.cpp

```
#include "x.h"
```

can I just entry a command with "X" as a parameter, then I can get

```
void X::f() {}
void X::g() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor should do what you wish. It has some [examples](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor/blob/master/srefactor-demos/demos.org) that show what it can do, and if I understood you correctly, Example 1 matches your use case. You might find the "[How can I automatically insert a prototype in foo.h from foo.c?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7694/how-can-i-automatically-insert-a-prototype-in-foo-h-from-foo-c)" thread helpful as well, it is very closely related.

Comment: this is exactly what I want.  thank you!